# Pager on GridView ASP.NET - How do I add an extra button at the end to Jump to the end page And Same for the Front Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2012, pager

[image]

I want to be ableto add a button after the '...' with this '>>' which jumps to the last page. And same for the front page.
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView Paging - First, Last, Next, Previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678384/gridview-paging-first-last-next-previous)

Comment: Look at the Mode in the Pager options.

Comment: Yep found it - I had to set the mode to Numeric First Last. Cheers